# In MS Excel a cell contains 15-10 how to separate the numbers ? Edit

Tags: excel

In MS Excel a cell A3 contains 15-10 and A4 Contains 9-9, A5 Contains 15-2. In B3 I Want 15+(10/12), in B4 I want 9+(9/12) Similarly in B5 I want 15+(2/12). How can i do this by a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting format.

Nonetheless, you can use this formula, obviously replacing `A1` with your particular cell:

```
= LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))/12
```

Answer (score 0):

In **B3** enter:

```
=--MID(A3,1,FIND("-",A3)-1) + MID(A3,FIND("-",A3)+1,9999)/12
```

and copy down

[image]

Similar to *foot-inch* conversion format.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `--` here? Typically I see this to convert an array of logical values to an array of numerical values, but here wouldn't the first `MID` return a numerical value anyway?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 The double unary is, indeed, superfluous.  However, if you check the return value for data type, you will see that the value returned by `MID` is, indeed, `text`.  However, the subsequent addition operator converts the value into a `number`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ah, good point. Never thought of the need to convert "text that looks like a number" to a "number". Like you said in this case it is unnecessary since the next operation takes care of this automatically, but I can see cases when this would be necessary. Thanks for the explanation.